# Lucene: Is there any way to know which subqueries have hit the document?

Tags: java, search, lucene

I have a MemoryIndex created like this.

````
```
        Version version = Version.LUCENE_47;
        Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer(version);
        MemoryIndex index = new MemoryIndex();
        index.addField("text", "Readings about Salmons and other select Alaska fishing Manuals", analyzer);
```
````

Then, I have a query containing a number of sub-query which is created from a set of concepts (including id, name, description). Right now I have to loop for every concept, generate a query, and finally check if it is matched => if it is, I append it to a string which is used to store matches

````
```
for (Concept concept : concepts) {
    Query query = queryGenerator.getQueryForConcept(concept);
    float score = query != null ? index.search(query) : 0.0f;
    if (score > 0) {
        matches.append(sep + concept.getId() + "|" + concept.getName());
        sep = "|";
    }
}```
````

The problem is: the number of concepts is growing larger and larger, which affects the performance. Is there anyway that I can create a one single query and compare to a document, and find out what concepts have been hit the document?
I tried using BooleanQuery as a whole, then add all subquery which derrived from concept into it. It matches but don't know which subquery hits, and even if we do, how do we put the details like "id", and "name" of a concept into it? 
Much appreciate all answers

Comment: Have you looked at `IndexSearcher.explain(...)`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried something like:
```
 Explanation explanation = searcher.explain(query, scoreDoc.doc); // #1
                System.out.println("----------");
                Document doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
                System.out.println(doc.get("title"));
                System.out.println(explanation.toString());
```
But don't really know how to use Explanation to check what queries hit, I'm new to Lucene :(